# MassTransit in ASP.NET MVC site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rabbitmq, esb, masstransit

I'd like to decouple a number of business objects that my website is using to support actions of the users.

My website is a SaaS/B2B site and I do not anticiapte to have a need for "mega scale".  My primary issue is a need to decouple business objects from each other, and perform occasional longer-running operations asynchronously - outside of execution of threads that handle user traffic.

Having said that, I really do not want to have a separate set of servers that process my messages, and would prefer for web servers to just host MassTransit or other Bus software) internaly in memory.  Assured message delivery (at this point) is also not yet my most important concenrn. I plan to "outsorce" a number of supporting business actions to the bus so that they do not pollute my main business services/objects.

Is this possible?  Do I need Loopback for now as a transport or do I need full RabbitMq?  Will RabbitMQ require me to install yet another set of servers to host it?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loopback is just for testing. Installing RMQ is the right path. You don't NEED different servers for it, but would suggest it. If you off load work to a bus, you don't really want that contending with resources for the website. Given that, you can run RMQ locally without any issue. It message volume is low, so is resource usage in RMQ. When you reacher higher volumes, IO can be a problem with RabbitMQ (or any MQ).

Comment: Got it, thank you.  If I have a variable number of web servers, will this matter from RMQ/MT perspective?  My web servers can scale up/down per demand

Comment: It will matter if you want them to talk to each other. Then you'll need a centralized RMQ instance. If you are okay with the jobs be localized to the webserver, then you can just add MT services + RMQ to your images and let your MT services work on stuff submitted from that webserver. This could cause you some problems, but I bet you could get away with it for a while at least.